# Does iOS have any library supporting to format number like NSNumberFormatter for Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, ios, formatting, format, string-formatting

I want to format a number to string by using a format string working like NSNumberFormatter for Mac OSX (NSNumberFormatter doesn't support format string). Does iOS have any library supporting to format number like NSNumberFormatter for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

[`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/) exists on iOS as well.

The only difference is it only supports the 10.4+ style of formatting, it does not support the legacy 10.0 style.

Comment: But it doesn't support format number with a formt string. That my problem :(Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @asedra_le: Learn how the 10.4+ style of formatting works. It's really not that hard, and can do everything the 10.0-style could.

Comment: Format number to string with 10.4+ style is OK. However, I need format number to string using a format string. That's problem :(

Comment: @asedra_le: Why do you specifically need to use a format string?

Comment: @Kevin_Ballard: That's customer requirement :(

Comment: @asedra_le: That's unfortunate. My only advice at this point is just write your own routine that parses the format string and sets the appropriate options on `NSNumberFormatter`.